# uglify task failed using grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have this inside init function:

```
uglify: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
```

Everything is running fine except the scripts files are not being uglified. I am getting an error like this:

```
Running "uglify:dist" (uglify) task
>> Destination dist/scripts/scripts.js not written because src files were empty.
```

I do have grunt inside package.json `"grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.7.0",`

```
>> No files created.
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says: The src files where empty.

See this [doc](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#basic-compression):

```
grunt.initConfig({
  uglify: {
      my_target: {
          files: {
              'dest/output.min.js': ['src/input1.js', 'src/input2.js']
          }
      }
  }
});
```

In your code you have specified the destination file as the source file.